# Div positioning vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

Is there a way to position div's like this:

```
|----------||----------||----------||----------|
|  div1    ||   div5   ||          ||   div10  |
|----------||----------||   div7   ||----------|
|  div2    ||          ||          ||   div11  |
|----------||   div6   ||----------||----------|
|  div3    ||          ||   div8   ||   div12  |
|----------||          ||----------||----------|
|  div4    ||          ||   div9   ||   div13  |
|----------||----------||----------||----------|
```

So what i'd like to do is having a horizontally expanding layout that doesn't scroll vertically, it just fills it with the space it has vertically and then moves horizontally.
 So the first element goes on the right top, second underneath it, third as well until there is no space left and then it goes back on top (like div5).

Comment: what you want are css columns, for which support is coming in CSS3, but isn't standardized yet.

Comment: You need to write a pretty custom Javascript to do this. jQuery will make it easier.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the vertical equivalent to how floated elements flow horizontally in a container (as if `float:top` were supported).

As @MarcB noted, in the future this will be easily doable with [CSS3 columns](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/). The standard hasn't been fully defined yet, but it may look something like the following:

```
.container {
    height: 200px;
    column-width: 100px;
    column-gap: 10px;
    column-fill: auto;
}
```

In the meantime, a jQuery plug-in may be the best bet. For example, jQuery Masonry has [one-column formatting](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/basic-single-column.html) that might do the trick. There may be simpler jQuery plug-ins out there that would also be adequate.

Related search terms: *jQuery*, *CSS columns*, *multi-column layout*, *tiled layout*, *mosaic layout*

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the blueprint CSS framework. I have used it to create a website which had a similar layout to your post, its very easy to use and fast too.

http://www.blueprintcss.org/